# Generating random number inside json file

Tags: json, random, dynamic, numbers

I want to give a random number in json file which is payload for the API post request. The "ssn" value in json file should be unique everytime. How do we do that?

```
"ssn": "Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000000)",
```

This doesn't work as it take the function as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
"ssn": Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000000),
```

Comment: Yes, It takes the whole line as string

Comment: have you tried removing the ( "  " )?

Comment: yes, "ssn": Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000000), <-- used without quotes, but it takes the function whole as a string & treats as a value

Comment: You can create a variable outside and use it inside a dynamic string and assess it to your key.

var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()* 1000000000)
"ssn": \`${rand}\`

Comment: I tried this & working: In json file --> "ssn": "#(ssn)" & in Feature file defined this variable --> *def ssn = '<number>'